# Sqlite comparing now to datetime is comparing date only

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using sqllite for android and I have a the completedDate in the db in the following format

```
2012-06-26 17:20
```

I am trying to get the all the rows of the Task table whose completed date is in the future (greater than now)

I do this

```
select * from Task where completedDate > datetime ('now')
```

The problem is that the comparison seems to be based on date only without the time stamp. I am getting all the rows with completed date that is starting from tomorrow. However if it is the date as today (regardless of the time) then I don't get the row

Why is that? Any pointet

Comment: Try putting completedDate inside of dateTime? I think I had a similar issue. And you may need to use the time functions on things in the db as well. If that is not the issue the in what format does `now` return the info?

Comment: I tried putting it but still no luck. I don't know what now return other than the documentation which says datetime is equiv to strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', ...)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in case anyone is interested.

Create a String representation of current date and do the comparison with it like the following

```
Date d = new Date();
String dStr = ..... //convert d to string using using simple date formated
select * from Task where completedDate > dStr
```